# How to validate if counter is getting increased using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Hi I have a scenario where i need to click on the like button and the likes counter on the feed screen will get incremented by 1 now i need to validate this counter using selenium if it is actually getting increased, since i don't know what was the old value and what is the new value.

Can we do this using selenium

Comment: can you provide the sample url for the same if possible

Comment: Its an mobile app but i can give you examples like facebook app or any app where upon like the like counts gets increased

Comment: Why do you not know the old value?!?! Why can you not read it from the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can do it like below

```
// this web-site shows counter ,its same like clicking on like button of face-book
// here instead of clicking we are refreshing the page or opening the same url again and again
driver.get("https://www.counter.gd/");

// finding the initial value of the counter is : 
String initialCounter = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='counter_id']")).getAttribute("value");
// printing the value of the counter, also converting the output type to int.
int countervalBefore = Integer.parseInt(initialCounter);
System.out.println("value of the counter before click/refresh is : " + countervalBefore);

// now refresh the page to increase the counter or click like button of the facebook to increase like counter
driver.navigate().refresh();

// now call the counter again
String afterCounter = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='counter_id']")).getAttribute("value");
int countervalAfter = Integer.parseInt(afterCounter);
System.out.println("value of the counter after click/refresh is : " + countervalAfter);

// now verifying the previous counter value with current counter value
if(countervalAfter > countervalBefore){
    System.out.println("Counter worked i.e incremented");
}else{
    System.out.println("Counter not working");
}
```

Hope this solves your query.

Comment: Thanks Raj It worked for me after little modification

Comment: m glad it worked if you think it helped you then please mark it as your answer